# Incorrect Usage of Union and Into

Tags: mysql

I have a query in MySQL

```
 select group_concat(users) into searchedUserIds from
    ((select user_id users from user_tbl)  union
    (select user_id  users from user_details )) a;
```

it gives the error: `incorrect usage of union and into`. What I want to do is to get all user ids into the variable `searchedUserIds`. `group_concat` will put all the ids in a single column and then I can save it into the `searchedUserIds` variable. This query is written inside a function which is giving me this error. This union query gives me results if I run it separately, but inside the function I get the error.

variable declaration:

```
declare
searchedUserIds varchar(5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

There has been a bug in some versions of MySQL. The error-message you are encountering is *supposed* to go off if the parser sees something like `SELECT ... INTO ... UNION SELECT ...`; that is, it's supposed to prevent the use of `INTO` in any branch of a `UNION` other than the last one. However, the way the check was written, it fails (in your MySQL version) to account for the possibility that the `UNION` is inside a subquery and the `INTO` is outside it.

The bug report is at http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32858; as you can see, the bug was fixed 5½ years ago, so the best fix is probably just to upgrade to a less ancient version of MySQL. (If you are already using a relatively recent version of MySQL, then perhaps they have had a new regression?)

If you do not wish to upgrade, or if you need to solve this problem sooner than you are willing to upgrade, then you can either rewrite your stored procedure to avoid the `INTO`, or rewrite your query to avoid the `UNION`. In your case, I imagine that every `user_id` in `user_details` will also appear in `user_tbl` anyway, so you can *probably* just write:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(users)
  INTO searchedUserIds
  FROM user_tbl
;
```

!

Comment: oh thanks a lot ruakh ! I was trying to fix this with suggestions given online. I wont be able to upgrade it soon enough to complete my project in time. And the query I need has joins with other tables.(the query above is the simplest form of the query i actually need) Soo I think what i can do is use two variables with two different queries. take those two variables, concatenate them finally and return.( :P for now ). and revelation about this bug makes me feel like a caveman. I will upgrade asap.thanks :)